# Visual Studio 2017 create new files with ansi encoding

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio 2017.
When I create a new view when developing asp.net core MVC, the new file is saved with ANSI encoding. To solve it, I need to open the file in Notepad++ and then change the encoding to UTF8 with BOM.

Update:
Its only asp.net views that are created in ANSI, all other files like .cs are in utf8 by default.

Comment: perfectly legitimate question.  Visual Studio 2017 uses different encoding by default than 2015 resulting in multiple end of line messages, problems with cli tools

Comment: For visual studio 2017 cut the file->save with encoding. I think it's too population in Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your ANSI files to UTF-8. I used notepad++ for that and symbols and accents render was fine then.

Also you can take a look at this post [MVC .net core is not displaying special characters correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45512883/mvc-net-core-is-not-displaying-special-characters-correctly/45577036#45577036)